# How do I get matchit to work with '/>' (self-closed tags)?

Tags: cursor-motions, filetype-javascript, plugin-matchit

I really like to jump from one `<el>` to the end of `</el>` with matchit. I am using it for jsx, but it does not seem to work if I have an element that is declared with `/>`, does anybody have an idea how to fix the issue.

Here is an example of what is not working:

```
<Scene key="tabbar" component={NavigationDrawer}  initial={true}>
  <Scene key="main" tabs={true} default="tab2" >
    <Scene key="tab1"  title="Tab #1" icon={TabIcon} navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor:"red"}} titleStyle={{color:"white"}}>
      <Scene key="tab1_1" component={TabView} title="Tab #1_1" onRight={()=>alert("Right button")} rightTitle="Right" />
      <Scene key="tab1_2" component={TabView} title="Tab #1_2" titleStyle={{color:"black"}}/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="tab2" initial={true} title="Tab #2" icon={TabIcon}>
      <Scene key="tab2_1" component={TabView} title="Tab #2_1"/>
      <Scene key="tab2_2" component={TabView} title="Tab #2_2" onLeft={()=>alert("Left button!")} leftTitle="Left" duration={1} panHandlers={null}/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="tab3" component={TabView} title="Tab #3" hideTabBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
    <Scene key="tab4" component={TabView} title="Tab #4" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
    <Scene key="tab5" component={TabView} title="Tab #5" icon={TabIcon} renderRightButton={()=><Right/>}/>
  </Scene>
</Scene>
```

I want for example to go from the first Scene open `<Scene>` to the end `</Scene>`. However when I press `%`, nothing happens.

Comment: Where do you want to jump if there's no closing tag?

Comment: No my issue is the first scene has a closing tag, but if i try to jump it does not.

Comment: I can't explain why but I confirm this behavior: without the self closing tags `<Scene.*/>`, `%` works properly and with them the matching doesn't work anymore. The weird part is that it seems to be happening only on your example file, because I have other html files with self closing tags and `%` behaves properly in them... Maybe it is due to the fact that all your tags are `Scene` but that seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the following lines in your `~/.vimrc`

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/macros/matchit.vim
filetype plugin on
```

If the offending  lines are in a `.html` file, then:

```
b:match_words = '<:>,' .
    \ '<\@<=[ou]l\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=li\>:<\@<=/[ou]l>,' .
    \ '<\@<=dl\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=d[td]\>:<\@<=/dl>,' .
    \ '<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

On the other hand, if they're in a `.jsx` file and you're using [vim-jsx](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx) (see [jsx.vim](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx/blob/master/after/ftplugin/jsx.vim#L13-L14)), then

```
b:match_words = '(:),\[:\],{:},<:>,' .
    \ '<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

Even though both values work well, It's necessary to take into account the following cases:

- There could be some `>` into some tags.
- There could be some tags with or without closing tags.

And you can do so by replacing

```
<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>
```

with

```
<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(\%(=\|/\)\@<!>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>
```

**Note:** When you're using a `.jsx` file but you aren't using any plugin, the `b:match_words` variable doesn't exist. In that case you could issue the following command:

```
:let b:match_words='(:),\[:\],{:},<:>,<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(\%(=\|/\)\@<!>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the above config, you can easily use `a<` from visual mode to select around closing tag, `i<` to select inner a closing tag.